# What's the actual difference between these set of commands in gcloud command-line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I have completed a basic lab in Qwiklabs platform. But I still don't get the difference between these set of commands.

To see what your default region and zone settings are, run the following commands:

```
gcloud config get-value compute/zone

gcloud config get-value compute/region
```

Identify your default region and zone

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project <your_project_ID>
```

Comment: One deals with regions, the other deals with zones!  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has regions, which are geographic areas. Within a region are zones, which are large data centers. A typical region has three or more zones within a region.

As of today, there are 28 regions and 85 zones. In addition, there are 146 network edge locations that are important for CDNs and network entry points into the Google Cloud network. Seven more regions are planned, raising the total number of regions to 35.

When you launch a service you need to specify the zone (usually). Some commands require specifying the region.

The CLI has variables to remember your preferred region and zone. These options can be modified via command-line options when executing individual commands.

[gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)

[Cloud locations](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations)

[Compute Engine Regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones)